# QUERYDSL: Unable to get query type for primary key in the inherited entity

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

All the entities I have inherit a parent class whose role is to generate the primary key. However when I'm trying to join two tables something like this from the documentation

```
 query.from(customer)
 .leftJoin(company).on(customer.company.eq(company.id))
.list(customer.firstName, customer.lastName, company.name);
```

However I do not have the Id field in generated query types.
Is there any alternative rather than using native queries as I also have filters which are dynamically generated as BooleanExpression which I want to pass in where clause.

Comment: can you please post the code for entity and query type?

Answer (score 0):

You need a @MappedSuperclass in you parent/super-class

If you derive from more than one super-class, you MUST tag all the super-classes with @MappedSuperclass to get the inherited fields. This is mandatory for QueryDSL.